# How to handle special characters in the password of a Postgresql URL connection string?

Tags: postgresql, url, connection-string, postgresql-9.1

Using a Postgresql URL connection string in the format of:

```
postgresql://user:secret@localhost
```

How do I handle special characters in that string (e.g., **$**) so that it will actually function when I connect to my postgres database?

I've tried simply URL encoding it, so for example, "test$" becomes "test%24" ... but that seems to be a problem as I get a "FATAL: password authentication failed " error when attempting to use it.

Comment: What method of URL encoding are you using exactly?

Answer (score 56):

See [Connection URIs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-connect.html#AEN39024) in the doc.

There are a few things that don't seem quite right in your question:

- URIs are supported by postgres since version `9.2` only, so with a `9.1` client that's not supposed to work at all. Or you're using a client that implements connection URIs itself.
- Percent-sign encoding is supported. Per doc:

  > Percent-encoding may be used to include symbols with special meaning
  >   in any of the URI parts.
- Percent-encoding is not even necessary for a dollar character.

Tried with 9.3:

`sql> alter user daniel password 'p$ass';`

```
$ psql 'postgresql://daniel:p$ass@localhost/test'
```

works

```
$ psql 'postgresql://daniel:p%24ass@localhost'
```

works

```
psql 'postgresql://daniel:pass@localhost/test'
```

fails as expected: bad password.

Comment: what if the special char would be te "@" sign ?

Comment: @Fjordo `@` must be passed in as `%40`. See also [this question](https://github.com/vitaly-t/connection-string/issues/15), against the right library to use for this ;)

Comment: Even I have the same issue , password with "@", I tries escaping with {@}, '''@''', """@""", raw(@), \@ etc. none of them worked for me.

Answer (score 9):

Maybe your input shell has a different encoding and `$` is not `%24`.
Check it out on https://www.urlencoder.org/

Hint:
If you use `alter user "username" password 'p$ass''word'` to set/change the password,
single quotes have to be masked with another singlequote.

Answer (score 1):

You can encode this kind of urls in browser console with [encodeURI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI):

For example get pg_dump command:

```
var DB_USER = 'postgres';
var DB_PASSWORD = 'password';
var DB_HOST = 'localhost';
var DB_PORT = '5432';
var DB_NAME = 'postgres';

var pghost = encodeURI(`${DB_USER}:${DB_PASSWORD}@${DB_HOST}:${DB_PORT}/${DB_NAME}`);
var pgdump = `pg_dump --dbname=postgresql://${pghost}`;

console.log(pgdump);
```

Answer (score 1):

just for any one who is strugling like me, i have a password like
`"a}1K&{LuGe}jw*BCasFdhxp83y7f"` in middle of my postgres connection string,
just encoding this part of url solved my issue, no need to encode the whole url

First String:

```
"postgres://root:a}1K&{LuGe}jw*BCasFdhxp83y7f@test-db.c1lri2mnc8os.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com:5432/aws-test"
```

Correct String:

```
postgres://root:a%7D1K%26%7BLuGe%7Djw%2ABCasFdhxp83y7f@test-db.c1lri2mnc8os.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com:5432/aws-test"
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed a solution for Golang and this is what I used

```
old_password := "@#foo#bar123$5454"
new_password := url.QueryEscape(old_password)
fmt.Println(new_password)

connect_str := fmt.Sprintf(`postgres://USERNAME:%s@HOST:PORT/DATABASE_NAME`, new_password)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my finding:
when I connect to postgresql server v15.5 that installed in Debian v10.2, I need to encode the hashtag # char in the password with %23
but when I connect to the pg server that installed in my local Windows 11 notebook, I can use the hashtag char in password string directly.
Fyi, I create the connection using python psycopg2. My python script run in WSL2

Comment: Please, [edit] and try for [answer], describe the effect of what you propose and explain why it helps to solve the problem. Find help with formatting your post here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting .