# supabase cannot connect to database

Tags: supabase

I've done a fresh install of Supabase via docker compose following [this example](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/hosting/docker) into my Ubuntu 20.04 server.  When I run docker-compose up everything works except I see this error in my logs:

```
supabase-rest | 21/Feb/2022:19:50:29 +0000: {"details":"could not translate host name \"l@db\" to address: Name does not resolve\n","code":"","message":"Database connection error. Retrying the connection."}
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at this section in the docker-compose.yml:

```sh
  rest:
    container_name: supabase-rest
    image: postgrest/postgrest:v9.0.0
    depends_on:
      - db
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      PGRST_DB_URI: postgres://postgres:${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}@db:5432/postgres
```

It's possible that the password you used in `.env` is not being escaped correctly - does it contain special chars?

Note that they need to be URI encoded if so as per: [How to handle special characters in the password of a Postgresql URL connection string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353623/how-to-handle-special-characters-in-the-password-of-a-postgresql-url-connection)