# Escaping special characters (@, #) in .env file and os.LookupEnv()

Tags: go, environment-variables

Struggling to get a postgres connection string into my app due to some special characters in the password. Everything I've tried hasn't work.

I've tried escaping with `\`, using the encoded values, have tried single quotes, single quotes within double quotes.

```
ACCOUNT_DB="postgres://postgres:abc@123#xAbs48a12!f#71a#987#21@121.0.0.1:5432/postgres?sslmode=disable"
```

Using `os.LookupEnv()` to fetch the variables.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to handle special characters in the password of a Postgresql URL connection string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353623/how-to-handle-special-characters-in-the-password-of-a-postgresql-url-connection)