# How to deal with an '@' symbol in postgres password

Tags: postgresql

So I have the url

`url = f"postgresql://{username}:{password}@{hostname}:{port_id}/{database}"`

And the password in the given url is: Test@123

Now when I pass this url to 'create_engine(url)', because of the '@' in the password, the hostname is getting read as, '123@hostname'.

How can I resolve this issue, keeping in mind that i cannot change the password.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to handle special characters in the password of a Postgresql URL connection string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353623/how-to-handle-special-characters-in-the-password-of-a-postgresql-url-connection) Especially [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353623/how-to-handle-special-characters-in-the-password-of-a-postgresql-url-connection#comment100364398_23361849).

Comment: It's a real shame Python doesn't support something like `str(URL(scheme='postgres', user=username, password=password, hostname=hostname, port=port_id, path=database))`… The `urllib.parse` un-parse functions are useless for escaping a `netloc`